# Angular-socket-io: how to disconnect the client

Tags: javascript, angularjs, socket.io

**Update**

Now the method [socket.disconnect(close) has been included in angular-socket-io](http://github.com/btford/angular-socket-io/issues/45). It has a Boolean parameter 'close', if true, closes also the underlying connection.

---

I am using btford/angular-socket-io

What is the correct approach to disconnect the client?

I am trying to implement the following scenario

1. user login --> connect to socket
2. user logout --> disconnect from socket
3. repeat (1) (2)

I succeeded to implement the connect (1) but I am having trouble with the disconnect (2)

This is what I tried: in my Authentication service I have the following

```
factory('AuthenticationService', function(socketFactory) {
  var mySocket;
  var service = {
      //...
      login: function(credentials) {
          var login = $http.post('/login', credentials);
          return login.then(function(response) {
            service.currentUser = response.data.user;
            if ( service.isAuthenticated() ) {
                // **connect to socket on login** 
                mySocket = socketFactory({ioSocket: io.connect('http://localhost')}); 
            }
            return service.isAuthenticated();
          });       
      },

      logout: function(redirectTo) {
          var logout = $http.get('/logout');
          logout.success(function() {
            service.currentUser = null;
            mySocket.disconnect();       // **disconnect on logout (not working)**
            redirect(redirectTo);
          });
          return logout;
      },
      //...
  };
  return service;
})
```

mySocket.disconnect();
gives the following error
TypeError: Object # has no method 'disconnect'

mySocket.disconnect() works if instead of

```
mySocket = socketFactory({ioSocket: io.connect('http://localhost')});
```

I use

```
mySocket = io.connect('http://localhost');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is very simple in fact :

Go edit the "socket.js" file from the Btford angular-socket module and you'll see :

```
var wrappedSocket = {

          on: addListener,

          addListener: addListener,



          emit: function (eventName, data, callback) {

            return socket.emit(eventName, data, asyncAngularify(socket, callback));

          },    


          removeListener: function () {

            return socket.removeListener.apply(socket, arguments);

          },



          // when socket.on('someEvent', fn (data) { ... }),

          // call scope.$broadcast('someEvent', data)

          forward: function (events, scope) {

            if (events instanceof Array === false) {

              events = [events];

            }

            if (!scope) {

              scope = defaultScope;

            }

            events.forEach(function (eventName) {

              var prefixedEvent = prefix + eventName;

              var forwardBroadcast = asyncAngularify(socket, function (data) {

                scope.$broadcast(prefixedEvent, data);

              });

              scope.$on('$destroy', function () {

                socket.removeListener(eventName, forwardBroadcast);

              });

              socket.on(eventName, forwardBroadcast);

            });

          }

        };
```

And then you just add this next to the others functions :

```
disconnect: function(){

                return socket.disconnect();

              },
```

And voilà, there you go :)

You should have something like that :

```
var wrappedSocket = {

          on: addListener,

          addListener: addListener,



          emit: function (eventName, data, callback) {

            return socket.emit(eventName, data, asyncAngularify(socket, callback));

          },



          disconnect: function(){

            return socket.disconnect();

          },



          removeListener: function () {

            return socket.removeListener.apply(socket, arguments);

          },



          // when socket.on('someEvent', fn (data) { ... }),

          // call scope.$broadcast('someEvent', data)

          forward: function (events, scope) {

            if (events instanceof Array === false) {

              events = [events];

            }

            if (!scope) {

              scope = defaultScope;

            }

            events.forEach(function (eventName) {

              var prefixedEvent = prefix + eventName;

              var forwardBroadcast = asyncAngularify(socket, function (data) {

                scope.$broadcast(prefixedEvent, data);

              });

              scope.$on('$destroy', function () {

                socket.removeListener(eventName, forwardBroadcast);

              });

              socket.on(eventName, forwardBroadcast);

            });

          }

        };
```

Comment: Yes, now socket.disconnect(close) has been included in angular-socket-io. https://github.com/btford/angular-socket-io/issues/45. It has a Boolean parameter 'close', if `true`, closes the underlying connection. I added the parameter in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

your code looks correct. I think the problem is variable hoisting, mySocket is hoisting.
read [here](http://conceptf1.blogspot.com.au/2014/01/javascript-best-practices-variable-scoping-and-hoisting.html)

Comment: Tanks, but hoisting should not be a problem, mySocket is declared only once at the beginning of the service. Also, it works if I do not use the socketFactory.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that [btford/angular-socket-io](https://github.com/btford/angular-socket-io) wraps the socket instance in the socketFactory 
but does not expose a disconnet() method
therefore it cannot be used to disconnect the socket from the client side.

Answer (score 0):

Just call the RsocketClient.close() method .[image]